# mysql use case in jpa query

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am building an endpoint where 3 query param comes in request like

status(mendatory)

searchCriteria(optional)

startDate(optional)

I am considering that i have to write three(3) native sql queries with combination of ex.
1: status and searchCriteria
2: status and startDate
3: status and searchCriteria and startDate
 but I do not want to write three queries,
I know it is possible to achieve in a single query using case .

This is my native sql query

```
@Query(value = "select * from email_info u where u.status =:status and  u.campaign =:searchCriteria and u.scheduleat =:startDate", 
  nativeQuery = true)
object  getPromotional(String status, String searchCriteria, String startDate);
```

How to use case in above query using jpa like

```
CASE
WHEN :searchCriteria != null THEN u.campaign =:searchCriteria
WHEN :startDate != null THEN u.scheduleat =:startDate
END
```

Comment: You should consider to use a Specification. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications

Comment: @Simon thanks for reply, I googled and i know I can achieve desired result by Query but syntatically I am unable to find example.